# verbose declare -x from .bashrc

Tags: bash, osx-snow-leopard

After using Migration Assistant (on OS X) to copy my files form a case *sensitive* file partition to a case *insensitive* file partition, my `.bashrc` has become verbose each time it is run.

```
#!/bin/bash
#.bashrc file
alias ls='ls -G'
alias sbrc='source ~/.bashrc'
export GNUTERM=x11
export NWCHEM_TOP=~/install/nwchem-6.0-binary
export
PATH = /opt/local/bin:$PATH
...
```

The output is now

```
Last login: Mon Apr 30 11:33:33 on ttys005
declare -x Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/tmp/launch-oblOxq/Render"
declare -x COMMAND_MODE="unix2003"
declare -x DISPLAY="/tmp/launch-VdU1C8/org.x:0"
declare -x GNUTERM="x11"
...
vencen@dirac:~$
```

How can I silence bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow my `.bashrc` file received an extra newline character leaving an isolated `export`

```
#!/bin/bash
export
PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
#...
```

The correct file

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
#...
```

does not generate the unwanted output, typing `export` on the command line does.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the problem, but I have seen situations where Migration Assistant leaves your home directory not owned by your user account.  Instead, your user account is granted all of the usual access via ACLs.  You might check that and try fixing it to see if that makes the problem go away.

To check: `ls -lde ~`

To fix:

```
sudo chown -R `id -u`:`id -g` ~
```